# Doubling a Matrix

Tags: java

I've created a two dimensional matrix and populated it with random numbers. I've then printed it out. I need help creating a second matrix that is twice the size of the first, and is populated with the numbers from the first one (which are now 2x2). For example:

Starting Matrix:

```
3   4  
2   1
```

Doubled Matrix:

```
3 3 4 4

3 3 4 4

2 2 1 1 

2 2 1 1
```

Comment: Specify the question

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;


public class MatrixDoubler {
    public static void main(String[] arg) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random rand = new Random();

        System.out.println("Enter the size of the matrix");

        int size = keyboard.nextInt();
        int A[][] = new int[size][size];

        for (int row = 0; row < size; ++row) {
            for (int col = 0; col < size; ++col) {
                A[row][col] = rand.nextInt(10);
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Matrix A:");
        printMatrix(A);

        int[][] B = doubleMatrix(A);

        System.out.println("Matrix B:");
        printMatrix(B);
    }

    private static int[][] doubleMatrix(int[][] A) {
        int rows = A.length;
        assert(rows > 0);
        int cols = A[0].length;
        assert(cols > 0);

        int B[][] = new int[rows * 2][cols * 2];

        for (int row = 0; row < rows * 2; ++row) {
            for (int col = 0; col < cols * 2; ++col) {
                B[row][col] = A[row / 2][col / 2];
            }
        }

        return B;
    }

    private static void printMatrix(int[][] M) {
        for(int i = 0; i < M.length; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < M.length; j++) {
                System.out.print(M[i][j] + " ");
            }

            System.out.println();   
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm no sure if that is what you are looking for but try this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < newMatrix.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < newMatrix.length; j++) {
        newMatrix[i][j] = matrix[i/size][j/size];
    }
}
```

Note: This code is surely not the best solution but a fast an easy one. It only works if both dimensions are the same size and it won't work if `newMatrix` is not exactly two times `matrix`. If it's always just to "double" a matrix it should work fine.

---

**Output:**
If you choose size 2 than it will output:

```
Enter the size of the matrix
2
The Matrix is
3 5 
5 2 
The newMatrix is
3 3 5 5 
3 3 5 5 
5 5 2 2 
5 5 2 2
```

and for size 3 it would be for example

```
Enter the size of the matrix
3
The Matrix is
4 4 3
5 9 4
7 4 1
The newMatrix is
4 4 4 4 3 3
4 4 4 4 3 3
5 5 9 9 4 4
5 5 9 9 4 4
7 7 4 4 1 1
7 7 4 4 1 1
```

It's not clear what you are asking but I hope this helps (:

Answer (score 0):

In Java 8 you can handle this pretty easily using maps and collectors. Here is a full example:

```
public class DoubleMatrix {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<List<Integer>> startingMatrix = Arrays.asList(
        Arrays.asList(3, 4),
        Arrays.asList(2, 1)
    );

    List<List<Integer>> doubleMatrix
        = startingMatrix.stream()
                        .map(innerList -> { //For each list
                          List<Integer> doubled = innerList.stream()
                                                           .map(element -> Arrays.asList(element, element)) //Return a list doubling each element
                                                           .flatMap(l -> l.stream())  //Flatten out/join all doubled lists
                                                           .collect(Collectors.toList());
                          return Arrays.asList(doubled, doubled); //Double the list
                        })
                        .flatMap(l -> l.stream())
                        .collect(Collectors.toList()); //Collect into a final list

    System.out.println(doubleMatrix);
  }
}
```

This avoids needing to know the size of the list beforehand, and is also tolerant of there being a difference between the width and height of your matrix - simply doubling every element in both directions.