# Doubling a 2-dimensional matrix in Java

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, matrix, 2d

I currently have a program that, when asked for an integer from the user, generates a square 2d matrix based on the input (i.e.,.: input of 2 results in a 2x2 grid).

The program then fills this matrix with random numbers 0-9, and then creates a new matrix that is double the size of the original (2x2 becomes 4x4, 3x3 to 6x6, etc.).

However, I cannot get the results to duplicate properly.  I'm trying to get the matrix to duplicate in such a way that from a matrix such as this:

`1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9`

It would produce a matrix of:

`1 1 2 2 3 3 
1 1 2 2 3 3 
4 4 5 5 6 6
4 4 5 5 6 6 
7 7 8 8 9 9 
7 7 8 8 9 9`

Currently, I'm just using two for loops to generate this matrix, but it doesn't print out the correct results.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Enter the size of the matrix.");
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    Random random = new Random();
    int n = keyboard.nextInt();
    int[][] matrix = new int[n][n];
    for (int x=0;x<n;x++)
    {
        for (int y=0;y<n;y++)
        {
            matrix[x][y] = random.nextInt(10); 
        }
    }
    System.out.println("The matrix is");
    for (int x=0;x<matrix.length;x++)
    {
        for (int y=0;y<matrix.length;y++)
        {
            System.out.print(matrix[x][y]+" ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
    int nDouble = n * 2;
    int c = 1;
    int[][] matrixDoubled = new int[nDouble][nDouble];
    for (int y=0;y<matrix.length;y++)
    {
        for (int x=0;x<matrix.length;x++)
        {
            matrixDoubled[x][y] = matrix[x][y];
            matrixDoubled[x+c][y] = matrix[x][y];
            matrixDoubled[x][y+c] = matrix[x][y];
            matrixDoubled[x+c][y+c] = matrix[x][y];
            c = c + 1;
        }
        c = 1;
    }
    System.out.println("The doubled matrix is");
    for (int x=0;x<matrixDoubled.length;x++)
    {
        for (int y=0;y<matrixDoubled.length;y++)
        {
            System.out.print(matrixDoubled[x][y]+" ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Drew, this looks like a homework task, which is not exactly the kind of question that people in StackOverflow would like to answer. People may understand that you're lazy and asking them to work for you for stackoverflow points. Also, if this is true, you would be unethical with your teacher and with yourself.

Comment: Same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34756346/doubling-a-matrix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The indices of the doubled matrix are wrong. They should be :

```
        matrixDoubled[2*x][2*y] = matrix[x][y];
        matrixDoubled[2*x+1][2*y] = matrix[x][y];
        matrixDoubled[2*x][2*y+1] = matrix[x][y];
        matrixDoubled[2*x+1][2*y+1] = matrix[x][y];
```

this way `matrix[0][0]` is mapped to positions `[0][0]`,`[1][0]`,`[0][1]`&`[1][1]` in the new matrix, `matrix[0][1]` is mapped to positions `[0][2]`,`[1][2]`,`[0][3]`&`[1][3]`, and so on...

Answer (score 1):

If thats the same problem as in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34756346/doubling-a-matrix) question that should do it:

```
for (int i = 0; i < matrixDoubled.length; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < matrixDoubled.length; j++)
        matrixDoubled[i][j] = matrix[i/size][j/size];
```

Note: This code is surely not the best solution but a fast an easy one. It only works if both dimensions are the same size and it won't work if `matrixDoubled` is not exactly two times `matrix`. If it's always just to "double" a matrix it should work fine.

---

**Output:**
If you choose size 2 than it will output:

```
Enter the size of the matrix
2
The Matrix is
3 5 
5 2 
The matrixDoubled is
3 3 5 5 
3 3 5 5 
5 5 2 2 
5 5 2 2
```

and for size 3 it would be for example

```
Enter the size of the matrix
3
The Matrix is
4 4 3
5 9 4
7 4 1
The matrixDoubled is
4 4 4 4 3 3
4 4 4 4 3 3
5 5 9 9 4 4
5 5 9 9 4 4
7 7 4 4 1 1
7 7 4 4 1 1
```

I hope this helps (: